# Media Query rules not taking priority

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I am working on a site, having a weird issue with a media query, some of the rules being overridden. It's for a template, so there is a base 'framework' CSS, and then another template specific CSS file that comes after. For clarity, this is the order in my HTML file

```
<link href="/themes/Base/base.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- Contains all of the base rules, including the base mobile rules-->
<link href="/themes/MyTheme/theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- Contains all of the theme specific overrides-->
```

In the `base.min.css` I have these rules:

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
....
#menu {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
min-height: auto;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
text-align: center;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
background-image: none;
}
....
```

Then in `theme.min.css` file, which comes after in the HTML file, I have these rules

```
....
#menu {
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
min-height: 320px;
width: 300px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
position: relative;
margin: -20px 0 0 0;
z-index: 100;
background-position: bottom right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(/themes/global/images/watermarks/watermark9.png);
}
....
```

Note that the second set of rules are not contained within a media query. Despite this, most of the rules in it are overriding the previous rules. The height, width, background image, etc. I assumed that the media query ones would have priority if everything else was equal (despite coming later) due to increased specificity.  I mean, I could slap a bunch of `!important;` on there if I need to, but that seems like a bandaid, not a solution.

Comment: Simple solution: put media queries at the bottom so that they override the defaults. The last rule always takes priority. Also make sure you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` at the top of head.

Comment: The media query is at the bottom of the framework CSS file, but that file comes before the other CSS file in the HTML. See the edit I just made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially your second set of CSS is a Media Query of "everything", and as it comes after the max-width rules it will also apply to the max-width 800px view.

Am I right in thinking some of these rules should not be applied under 800px? If so, put them in a min-width rule and then they won't be used. For example in theme.css:

```
#menu {

    /*Put rules for any width in here*/

}    

@media all and (min-width: 801px) {
    #menu {
        /*Put rules you don't want inherited by max 800 in here*/
        min-height: 320px;
        width: 300px;
        ...
    }
}
```